# Angular Interpolation Binding does not show date if format is not "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date, input

My interpolation binding doesn't work if the given format is not 'yyyy-MM-dd'

`.html:`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>DOB
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birth_date" value={{stu.result.birth_date}}>
  </label>
</div>
```

In this problem, the current format of the date is `MM/dd/yyyy`, so the interpolation binding doesn't work as expected and only shows plain `MM/dd/yyyy`  (without the corresponding data as the value) on the input box. But if the format is `yyyy-MM-dd`, it works without problem (this worked because there are a few data have this format, and the others are on another format). Is there any solution I can use to fix this problem? Or, could anyone propose a new way to do `POST` request and the data sent is in `yyyy-MM-dd` format? Because every time I do a POST request, the data sent to the server is in `MM/dd/yyyy` format, not the wire format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Here is the `html` used for sending the data:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="birth_date">DOB:</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birth_date" [(ngModel)]="birth_date" name="birth_date"
      name="tanggal_lahir">
</div>
```

and this is the chunk of`TypeScript` file used for sending the data:

```
this.http.post(this.urlApi, {
 birth_date: this.birth_date
}, this.httpOptions).subscribe(.....);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make date formats consistent across your application.

In your typescript code you can change date format using inbuilt angular DatePipe.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(public dateFormatPipe: DatePipe){
}

this.http.post(this.urlApi, {
 birth_date:  this.dateFormatPipe.transform(this.birth_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
}, this.httpOptions).subscribe(.....);
```

Now you also need to add DatePipe to providers in your module configuration.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [DatePipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```